# RewriteRule multiple arguments for 1 file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i need help with rewrite rules.
I have URL structure like this - `index.php?page=team&id=45`
but i have also `index.php?page=news&page=1` or simply without parametr - `index.php?page=download` ....

Is it posible to make rewrite rules for each ?page parametr ?
For example : `index.php?page=news&page=25` --> `/news/25`
and `index.php?page=team&id=45` --> `/team/45`

I have this rewrite rule `RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA]` but it change only &page= and not the other parameters.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it this way.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\ /+index\.php\?page=(team|news)&(?:id|page)=([^\s&]+)
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^team/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=team&id=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^news/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=news&page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: thanks, its working... but i have styles and images loaded from "current dir" so when i do this rewriterule, my css and images can't load. do you know way how to fix it ? i dont want to rewrite every path to js / css / img

Comment: no, to fix JS/CSS just add this to the head section of your html. `<base href="http://www.yoursite.com" />`